# Block access for IP for custom URL (query_string)

Tags: nginx, deny

nginx 1.19.9

I have URLs like this

- `https://example.com/test?mindbox-message-key=...`
- `https://example.com/men?mindbox-message-key=...`
- `https://example.com/women?mindbox-message-key=...`
- `https://example.com/chile?mindbox-message-key=...`

and I need to block some IP. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    ...

    location /my-custom-url {
        if ($args ~* "mindbox-message-key") {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```